# What does this traceback mean: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to pull data the CDC and put the data into a database. My most recent traceback is: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. And do not know what that means or how to fix my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import ssl
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('cdcdata.sqlite')
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CState (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
state_id INTEGER, State TEXT, Count INTEGER)''')

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CDate(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
date_id INTEGER, state_id INTEGER,  Date INTEGER, Count INTEGER)''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE State_COIVD_Numbers (State TEXT, state_id INTEGER, date_id INTEGER, count INTEGER)''')

# 

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

data = open('rows.json', encoding='utf8').read()
info = json.loads(data)

for data in info['meta']['view']['columns']:
    data1 = data['position']
    if data1 != 1:
        continue

    date_data = data['cachedContents']['top']
    cur.execute("SELECT Date FROM CDate WHERE Count= ?", (date_data,))
    cur.fectone()
    #print(date_data)

for data in info['meta']['view']['columns']:
    data1 = data['position']
    if data1 != 2:
        continue
    state_data = data['cachedContents']['top']
    cur.execute("SELECT State FROM CState WHERE Count= ?", (state_data,))
    cur.fetchone()
    # print(state_data)

cur.execute('''INSERT INTO CState(State, Count) VALUES(?,?)''',(state_data,))
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO CDate(Date, Count) VALUES(?,?)''', (date_data,))
cur.execute('''select CState.State, CDate.Date FROM CState join CDate on State_COVID_Numbers.state_id=state.id''' )
cur.execute('''select CDate.Date, CState.State FROM CDate join CState on State_COVID_Numbers.date_id=date.id''' )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
Print('You Did It!')
```

I am new to coding and I have tried many things, but I do not know what to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code? I tried to fix the formatting but couldn't fix the indentation. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I fixed the indentation.

Comment: Which line gives the error? The SELECTs each have one param (`?`), the INSERTs each have two params, but the same arguments are sent (a one element tuple).

Comment: I get the traceback on this line:

Comment: cur.execute("SELECT Date FROM CDate WHERE Count= ?", (date_data,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.